# Closed form solutions to a Gaussian equation

Tags: probability, gaussian-integral, transcendental-equations

Let $\phi(t) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\{-t^2/2\}$ be the standard Gaussian pdf function and $\Phi(t) := \int_{-\infty}^t \phi(u)du$ be the Gaussian CDF function. Consider equation
$$
\Phi(x) + \phi(x) = 1.
$$

I'm wondering whether such an equation has simple closed-form solutions $x$?

Comment: If you still interested in an answer give a reply.

Comment: Looks like $x=39.9$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BPDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+1%5D,+39.9%5D%5D%2BN%5BCDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B0,+Sqrt%5B1%5D%5D,+39.9%5D%5D).